# X.org working with no socket in chroot?

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, chroot, socket

I have a chroot setup and I've been running graphical applications from it with no problem. The only setup I've done is set `DISPLAY=:0` and it works. However I always thought Unix domain sockets were used for X11 so I couldn't figure out why this was working. I did a little digging and it turns out I was right. My X.org server is launched with the `-nolisten tcp` flag and I have a unix domain socket in `/tmp/.X11-unix` yet somehow my chroot can launch graphical applications on that X11 display without any socket. I never hard linked the socket to the chroot, in fact they're not even on the same file system. `/tmp/.X11-unix` is completely empty on the chroot. How is it possible that my chroot can launch graphical applications on my X11 display?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The X server also supports abstract sockets, which work identically to UNIX sockets, and have pathnames similar to UNIX sockets, but the pathnames start with a NUL character.  See the documentation for "abstract" in the [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) manpage.  An abstract socket effectively exists in all filesystem namespaces and chroots; you don't have to link anything into the chroot or namespace to use it.

Perhaps the X server and client are both using an abstract socket to communicate?  X clients using the standard X client libraries will automatically attempt to use an abstract socket, *before* they try to use the default UNIX socket.  In libxcb, see `_xcb_open` and `_xcb_open_abstract` in [src/xcb_util.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/libxcb/tree/src/xcb_util.c).

Comment: This is interesting. I'll take a look and see if that's what's going on.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be it. `netstat` reveals a socket called `@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` and from looking around the @ seems to symbolize it's abstract.

Comment: Note that abstract sockets are a Linux-specific extension to portable Unix sockets.  Per the [Linux `unix.7` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html):  "Linux also supports an abstract namespace which is independent of the filesystem." and "The abstract socket namespace is a nonportable Linux extension."